# Remove entire image if image source is within a specific directory

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to strip out any html code of images from content if the image path is within a specific directory.

Take for example this block of content:

```
Donec iaculis <img src="http://www.domain.tld/smilies/butterfly.gif" alt="butterfly.gif" /> arcu pretium elementum et posuere felis. <img alt="mrgreen.gif" src="http://www.domain.tld/smilies/mrgreen.gif" /> Duis sit amet erat vitae tellus eleifend varius. <img src="http://www.domain.tld/avatars/somedude.jpg" /> Pellentesque ac ligula
```

What I am after is:

```
Donec iaculis arcu pretium elementum et posuere felis. Duis sit amet erat vitae tellus eleifend varius. <img src="http://www.domain.tld/avatars/somedude.jpg" /> Pellentesque ac ligula
```

In this example I would need to have the two images's removed that contain `/smilies/` and leave the one img that exists within the `/avatars/` path.

Note that the alt="" is in two different locations on the two images it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$html = 'Donec iaculis magna eget <img src="http://www.domain.tld/smilies/butterfly.gif" alt="butterfly.gif" /> arcu pretium elementum et posuere felis. Vivamus eget sodales lorem, id dictum lorem. Nunc vitae facilisis nibh. Integer dignissim, diam non molestie luctus, libero lacus auctor eros, vel hendrerit lorem risus vel elit. Pellentesque ac magna nec lectus tristique blandit. <img src="http://www.domain.tld/smilies/mrgreen.gif" /> Duis sit amet erat vitae tellus eleifend varius. <img src="http://www.domain.tld/avatars/somedude.jpg" /> Pellentesque ac ligula eget lacus dapibus fermentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi gravida tempor leo eget lacinia. Curabitur interdum diam in congue consequat.';

$baseurl = 'http://www.domain.tld';
$folder = '/smilies/';

$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagname('img');
$removeList = array();
foreach ($images as $domElement) {
    $src = $domElement->getAttribute('src');
    if (strpos($src, $baseurl . $folder) !== false) {
        $removeList[] = $domElement;
    }
}

foreach ($removeList as $toRemove) {
    $toRemove->parentNode->removeChild($toRemove);
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

Care that you have to do two separate foreach loops, as you can't remove DOMNode from a DOMNodeList you are iterating. This is also the problem with Casimir's answer I think.

Comment: I am simply wanting to have the image html code removed from the html code.

Comment: I've added the removal from the DOM tree. Read the notice at the end of the code.

Comment: Now that is just an odd way to have to go about something that is totally based on parent/children dependants. thanks for this Langdi - and I hope you were able to learn something from it too!

Answer (score 0):

An example using the DOM:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($yourHTML);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $imgNode) {
    if (strpos('/smilies/', $imgNode->getAttribute('src')))
        $imgNode->parentNode->removeChild($imgNode);
}
$yourHTML = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Hello, this only removed the very first image of the two it should have removed. Thoughts on getting it to remove all of the images that match?